# self.delegate is always nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

I saw similar questions like this. In all the place they said to use `className.delegate = self` or other similar solutions. But i already checked i have did everything correctly. Then also i am facing self.delegate is nil problem.

I am trying to pass data from MyViewController to NextViewController on Button Click

I did,

1.Created Protocol in MyViewController

2.Created delegate Instance in MyViewController

3.Wrote this code in Button Click Event

```
-(void)buttnPressed:(id)s{

    NextViewController* d=[[NextViewController alloc]init];

    if(self.delegate){
        NSLog(@"D");
    }
    if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(groupSelected:)]) {
        [self.delegate groupSelected:@"df"];
    }
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:d animated:YES];
}
```

4.Implemented FirstViewController in NextViewController and set it's delegate
5.Created FirstViewController's instance (inside NextVC) and using that instance i set it's delegate as self 
6.Implemented the delegate method in NextVC

I did everything correctly to my knowledge but i did not get the solution. Please help. Thanks for the time. (:

Here is my code

**MyViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@protocol WatchListDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)groupSelected:(NSString *)grouDetails;

@end


@interface MyViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong,nonatomic) id<WatchListDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

**MyViewController.m**

```
#import "MyViewController.h"
#import "NextViewController.h"

@interface MyViewController ()
@property UIButton *buttonPopUp;
@end

@implementation MyViewController

-(id)init{
    self = [super init];
    return self;
}

-(void)loadView{
   [super loadView];
    self.buttonPopUp=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [self.buttonPopUp addTarget:self
                         action:@selector(buttnPressed:)
               forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.buttonPopUp setTitle:@"Press ME" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.buttonPopUp setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    self.buttonPopUp.frame=CGRectMake(80,180,80,40);
    [self.view addSubview:self.buttonPopUp];
}


-(void)buttnPressed:(id)s{

    if(self.delegate){
        NSLog(@"D");
    }
    if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(groupSelected:)]) {
        [self.delegate groupSelected:@"df"];
    }
    NextViewController* d=[[NextViewController alloc]init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:d animated:YES];
}
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
@end
```

**NextViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MyViewController.h"

@interface NextViewController : UIViewController<WatchListDelegate>

@end
```

**NextViewController.m**

```
#import "NextViewController.h"

@interface NextViewController ()

@end

@implementation NextViewController


-(id)init{
    self = [super init];
    if(self){
        MyViewController *m=[[MyViewController alloc]init];
        m.delegate = self;
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)loadView{
    [super loadView];

}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}


-(void)groupSelected:(NSString *)grouDetails{
    NSLog(@"groupSelected");
}
@end
```

Thanks for the time (:

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly, but it looks like you create an instance of `MyViewController` as a local variable in `init`.  That variable goes out of scope two lines later (the closing brace of the `if` statement), which means the instance you actually display is a different one, in which the delegate property is not set.

Comment: I tried global variable too.. Created as a @property in .h file and then initialized here. But still delegate was nil

Comment: @Avi is right. Also it is not clear to me if MyViewController calls NextViewController or viceversa. Anyway, who implements the WatchListDelegate protocol is NextViewController, but it seems to me that should be implemented by MyViewController class

Comment: the mechanism is this: if a controller A pushes a controller B and B need to *call* the parent A, then B should have a delegate property set to A. This way B can *call* methods of A controller. So A must implement the protocol

Comment: I need to navigate from MyVC to NextVC, hence using NextVC's instance i am pushing the view. When i click the Button in MyVC, data should be passed from MyVC to NextVC.

Comment: if you want to push data from MyViewController to NextViewController then you can simply give , why you need delegate in this case

Comment: so MyVC pushes NextVC and when a button in NextVC is pressed, then some data should be pushed back to MyVC, right?

Comment: @ddb I need to pass Data from A to B , **Not** B to A.

Comment: If you are going from `My` to `Next`, having an instance of `My` in next, whether a local variable or an instance variable, is wrong.  You already have an instant of `My` -- the one that displayed `Next`.  It seems like you have things the wrong way around.  `Next` should have a delegate property that is set when `Next` is displayed by `My`.

Comment: @jagveer I am using delegate to pass data , not for navigation

Comment: @ddb Button is in A. When button is pressed, some data from A should be transfered to B

Comment: so, I'll try again. MyVC pushes NextVC on the VC stack, but if you press a button that is in MyVC, then some data should be sent trom MyVC to NextVC, right?

Comment: @ddb Exactly.... Sorry for late reply..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
-(void)buttnPressed:(id)s{

     NextViewController* d= [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VCidentiferFromStoryBoard"];
    self.delegate = d;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:d animated:YES];
    if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(groupSelected:)]) {
        [self.delegate groupSelected:@"df"];
    }
}
```

Comment: I am doing programatically.. not using storyboard

Comment: Ok Then replace first line with yours:NextViewController* d=[[NextViewController alloc]init];

Comment: @EmmieCapps where you define you delegate in MyViewController or NextViewController?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need a delegate to pass data, you're trying to pass the string value 'df'? If so you could just create a public property in NextViewController and assign it a value when you create NextViewController in MyViewController?

The delegate is nil, because it does not look like you set it, so in the button pressed logic you would do `self.delegate = d;`, don't assign the delegate or create MyViewController in the init of NextViewController, then check the delegate and it won't be nil, but I don't think you need the delegate pattern in this case?

Let me know if you need me to clarify or there is something else in particular you need to pass.

Answer (score 0):

1. Edit your **MyViewController.m**

   ```
   @implementation MyViewController
   {
       NextViewController* nextViewController;
   }
   ```
2. Then rewrite the `buttnPressed` method like below:

   ```
   -(void)buttnPressed:(id)s
   {
       if(!nextViewController) // this way only one time NextVC will be created
       {
           nextViewController = [[NextViewController alloc]init];
           [self.navigationController pushViewController:nextViewController animated:YES];
           self.delegate = nextViewController;
       }
       if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(groupSelected:)]) {
           [self.delegate groupSelected:@"df"];
       }
   }
   ```